# Common Lisp -- is it possible to define "unlet"?

Tags: common-lisp

Most of the functions I write are really small and relatively few of them are recursive. Does Common Lisp provide a way to prevent recursion by "unbinding" the name of the function inside its body. Alternatively, does it provide a way to unbind the function value of a symbol so that I can roll my own explicitly non-recursive `defun`?

I'd like to be able to do something similar to the following, possibly hidden behind a macro.

```
(defun non-recursive-func (arg)
  (unflet (non-recursive-func)
    (+ (first arg) (second arg))))
```

I accidentally wrote some buggy code today where a wrapper function delegated to itself instead of the unwrapped function, and it made me realize that preventing recursion with some compile-time mechanism could be useful.

```
(defun fcompose-2 (f g)
  (lambda (x) (funcall f (funcall g x))

(defun fcompose (&rest args)
  (reduce #'fcompose-2 args))
```

Except that I had accidentally written the following for definition for `fcompose`.

```
(defun fcompose (&rest args)
  (reduce #'fcompose args))
```

naturally leading to a stack overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
(defmacro defun* (name (&rest args) &body body)
  `(defun ,name ,args
     (flet ((,name ,args 
              (declare (ignore ,@args))
              (error "~a is defined with defun* and cannot be called from itself" ',name)))
       ,@body)))
```

This adds a internal binding in the function scope that just signals an error if it is used in the body and you can replace `defun*` definition with `defun` for production.

Comment: I was trying to think of other ways to do this that wouldn’t ever have the function name in scope but I think this way is least likely to confuse the optimiser

Comment: If you `macrolet` instead of `flet` you could catch the error at compile time.  Also probably want to use `alexandria:parse-body` to get declarations and documentation right and... this probably isn't worth it in the real world.

Comment: @SteveLosh How can `(someop somefunnamebinding)` be caught at compile time? It's like fixing the halting problem.

Comment: `(macrolet ((foo (&args) (error "Unexpected recursion"))) (foo 1 2))` will signal an error at macroexpansion time (which will happen when you compile).  It won't catch everything, like `(bar #'foo)`, so it's probably worth also doing the `flet` to catch those at runtime.

Comment: No, I take it back, you really don't need the `flet`.  `(foo ...)` in the body will signal an error at macroexpansion time.  `(funcall #'foo)` will also signal an error because `foo` is a macro, not a function (at least in SBCL and CCL -- the spec technically allows implementations to not signal for performance reasons).  It's not gonna save you from *everything*, e.g. `(funcall (read-from-string "foo"))`, but it can catch most of what the parent is looking for at compile time.

Comment: @SteveLosh `(defun fcompose (&rest args) (reduce #'fcompose args))` was the OPs example, but i generalized it to `(let ((somfunnamebinding 'fcompose)) (reduce somfunnamebinding args))` in my comment. It won't be catched at compile time.

Comment: Sure, it's impossible to catch *everything*.  The `flet` won't prevent `(funcall 'foo)` either, so you may as well use `macrolet` so it'll catch what it can at compile time instead of runtime.